# Multiple instances of the same target for make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a Makefile written by someone else in my lab and I see the following:

```
include /path/to/Makefile.inc

TARGET_A: pre_req_1 pre_req_2
    cmd_1;
    cmd_2;
    ...
```

When I look at `/path/to/Makefile.inc` I see that it also includes a target `TARGET_A`
with **other** pre-requisites and recipes.

Is this a normal practice? (and would it work?) Would `make` treat the two rules separately? Can we safely make any assumptions about which one is considered first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a dangerous practice since it is confusing to know which one is applied.

The "include" will act has if the included file content was in the Makefile, and the targets will be overrided while reading the Makefile. So, the last target will be honored, and the first one (in the included file) will be ignored.